# Read text file line by line in C#

Tags: c#, file, io

I am trying to read a text file line by line inside a textbox, but it returns only the word "!MANAGERS" in the textbox.

My text file is:

```
!MANAGERS
NUMBERS = 6
ADMIN = 1
!INFORMATIONS
741852:PAULO MARCO:MANAGER:TEAM
```

My code to get the file is:

```
public static string GetFile () {
    string filepath = @"C:\Files\projectmanager.txt";
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (filepath);
    string lines = reader.ReadLine ();
    var list = new List<string> ();
    list.Add (lines);
    string[] liness = list.ToArray ();

    foreach (string line in liness) {
        return line;
    }

    return "ERROR";
}
```

My textbox code is:

```
String filetext = ToolLibrary.FileSystem.GetFile();
textbox1.Text = filetext;
```

Comment: Please look at the docs on Microsoft site. For example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-read-a-text-file-one-line-at-a-time

Comment: Also if you want to add each line text to a separate text box then you need `n` text boxes where `n` is number of lines in file. Also you need to return appropriate value from function that can be useful for assigning value to text box

Comment: As per you code `"!MANAGERS"` this is correct value in textbox1, what is your expected result. Did you try to debug code and understand what is going wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an option for you, this can be done in one line provided you have set Multiline to true on your textbox properties.

[image]

```
textbox1.Lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Files\projectmanager.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write

```
textbox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(filepath);
```

Also, set the `Multiline` property of the text box to `true`. (You can do so in the properties window.)